# how can i use opencv in python3.2 with linux system

Tags: python, opencv

I have download some package pencv,it does not work in python3.2,but it do work in python2.7, all the correlated packages I have  downloaded,how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as Ubuntu (13.04) is concerned, the packages (python-opencv-2.4.2) in the repo are seemingly for Python 2.7 only, as stated in this [Launchpad post](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/amd64/python-opencv/2.4.2+dfsg-0exp2ubuntu1). I haven't been able to import cv2 in ipython3 either.